# PHP Form executing POST request on load

Tags: php, forms

I am creating an update form, but when I click on the update button it redirects to my update page, and triggers the POST request which makes it a valid post and does not ask for any information to update.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php require ('template/functions.php');
    $ID = $_GET['id'];
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM specialties WHERE id='".$ID."'";
    $results = mysqli_query($connect,$sql_query);
    $spc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
    $error = "";
    $specialist_section = false;
    $description_section = false;
    $specilist_exist = false;
    $valid_post = true;
    ?>
    <?php 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "post") {
        valid();    
        if ($valid_post){
            $sql_query = "UPDATE specialties SET ";
            $sql_query .= "specialty='".$_POST['specialty']."',";
            $sql_query .= "description='".$_POST[description]."'";
            $sql_query .= " WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql_query);
            if (!results){
                print "MYSQL_ERROR: ".mysqli_error($connect);
                $valid_post = false;
                $specilist_exist = true;
                $error .= "Specialty already exist <br/>";
            }

        }else{
            $valid_post = false;
        }
    }
    ?>  
    <head>
        <title>Specialist Lookup </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php 
                if ($valid_post){?>
                    <h2>Update Complete</h2>                
                    <?php
                }else{
                    if ($error) { ?>
                        <h3 style="color:red;"><?php echo $error ?> </h3> <?php }?>
                        <h1>Update Specialist</h1>          
                        <form  action="update.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="specialty" style="color:<?php if ($specialist_section){echo "red";}else{ echo "black";} ?>">Specialty:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sp" name="specialty" value="<?php echo $spc['specialty'] ;?>" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description"  style="color:<?php if ($description_section){echo "red";}else{ echo "black";} ?>">Description:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="description"><?php echo $spc['description'] ; ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>  
        <div>
    </body>
<?php
    require ('template/footer.php');
?>

/*Reference for the function*/
function valid(){
    $valid_post = true;
    if (empty($specialty)) {
                $valid_post = false;
                $specialist_section = true;
                $error = "Please fill in the Specialist section";

            }

            elseif (empty($description)) {
                $valid_post = false;
                $error = "Please fill in the description section";
                $description_section = true;
            }

            elseif (empty($description) and empty($specialty)) {
                $valid_post = false;
                $error = "Please fill in the specialty and description section";
                $description_section = true;
            }
            else{
                $valid_post = true;
            }

}
```

Comment: What is your question.

Comment: Is an implicit "why post is valid even if I never sent the form?"

Comment: Please let us what is the issue that you are facing..

Comment: http://jeff.blared.net/specialist/ - here is the site
when I try to update the DB in the update - valid_post value gets set  Immediately without going through the validation (not having chance to submit changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you set

```
    $valid_post = true;
```

You need to change the logic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php require ('template/functions.php');
    ...
    $valid_post = false;
    ?>
    <?php 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "post") {
        $valid_post = valid();  
        if ($valid_post){
            // ...
        }
    }
    ?>  
    <head>
        <title>Specialist Lookup </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php 
                if ($valid_post){?>
                    <h2>Update Complete</h2>                
                    <?php
                }else{
                    // ...
                } 
                ?>  
        <div>
    </body>
```

I do not know what happens in valid() function. But I suggest you this pattern:

```
$validPost = false;
if (valid()) {
    $validPost = true;
}
```

or

```
$validPost = valid();
```

Comment: I tried most it (aside from change the validation ):

Comment: Here is the site: http://jeff.blared.net/specialist/ 
I attempted to make $valid_post to be true right away unless the IF statement changes it. but it doesn't seem to make it a valid post

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how you write your `valid()` function.

By looking at the code, `$valid_post` is set to be true by default, so you might want to have a look at your `valid()` function to see if it is actually setting `$valid_post` to be false if it is not valid, otherwise it will always trigger your update function even if there is no valid form data.

if your `valid()` function is returning boolean then just modify your code
change

`valid()`

to

`$valid_post = valid()`

Also, you probably dont need `else` in your code at all, `$valid_post = valid()` this will simply assign a `boolean` value already, therefore the `else` part will be redundant.

Let me know if you have any question